# Compiling my own Blender hybrid with Cycles 2.93 and everything else 3.2?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, opencl, compile

I understand there are two python versions at play in this scenario, I think.

Blender 2.93 had OpenCL and currently I'm stuck with an AMD R9 390x 8gb which performs fantastically in Cycles pre-3.0 but as you know OpenCL was dropped like errant taco meat. I was enjoying 3.2 but not being stuck using my CPU for rendering so I find myself back in 2.93. I would love to be in the CUDA crowd but that's not in the cards being on the social assistance. So all that out of the way is it possible before I endeavor down this path and become hyperfocused on it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about compiling and developing Blender in C so off topic.

Comment: It will not be practical to attempt this. It's better to dedicate your efforts to getting a new GPU. You can also have a look at render farms like SheepIt.